# How do create an encrypted system with multiple Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, dual-boot, encryption, storage

A few weeks ago I created a completely encrypted system on a notebook and must say I like the idea. It's a little bit annoying to enter the password on every boot, but it's nice to know even if I lose the computer, I don't give my data to other people. With the [alternate-cd](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/System_verschl%C3%BCsseln/Alternate_Installation) it's easy to do.

Now I have to setup a new system where I want to combine the new idea with my usual usage strategy. There I have more partitions: 3 system, Home, Different Data Partitions for vm-data, photo-data and mp3-data. The background is that I prefer not to update a system. I prefer to install the new version parallel to the old system. So I can easily test it.
Obviously the Data Partitions are used for both systems.

My questions is, how can I easily combine both my strategy and the crypto-approach? Or is it impossible? The way to do the encrypted stuff by [hand](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/System_verschl%C3%BCsseln) is in my eyes too complicated.

Comment: do you want to encrypt the data partition also?

Comment: yes all partitions should be encrypted.

Comment: Before I answer, let me see if I got it right, you need: 3 x system partitions, 1 x home, 3 x data partitions? If so I think I have an approach but I think it needs some manual configuration.

Comment: Yes you are right. I get at ask ubuntu a link to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36434/install-backtrack-5-r2-into-running-luks-setup-installed-with-ubuntu/36490#36490 which looks very complicated.