# How to hide timestamps on encrypted data files with ecryptfs?

Tags: ecryptfs

I was [investigating using ecryptfs to encrypt a single directory in my computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/how-to-encrypt-individual-folders/1291482#1291482), but one of the things I noticed was that it leaks timestamps operations on unencrypted files in the lower encrypted data files, as also mentioned at: [conceal home folder completely - is ecryptfs the right choice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59556/conceal-home-folder-completely-is-ecryptfs-the-right-choice/60108#60108) which could considerably help attackers in identifying the files.

Is there a way to hide those timestamps, e.g. by using a fixed timestamp for every single data file? I understand that the file sizes can also help the attacker, but that I can live with (hmmm or can I? Can the attacker uniquely determine the exact size of an encrypted file from an unencrypted version of it? For another question I guess).

You can reproduce this with:

```
export ECRYPTFS_DIR="$HOME/ecryptfs"
export ECRYPTFS_DATA_DIR="$HOME/.ecryptfs-data"

sudo mount -t ecryptfs \
      -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes \
      "$ECRYPTFS_DATA_DIR" \
      "$ECRYPTFS_DIR"
echo AAAA > ~/ecryptfs/aaaa
echo BBBB > ~/ecryptfs/bbbb
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=1k > ~/ecryptfs/zzzz
sudo umount "$ECRYPTFS_DIR"
ls -l "$ECRYPTFS_DATA_DIR"
```

which will show the correct timestamp on those files.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, Linux kernel 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't hide timestamps. If you want to hide metadata such as timestamps and file sizes (which are more likely to breach privacy than time stamps), you need whole-disk (or whole-partition) encryption.

There may be a way to force the mtime (content modification time) to be different (actually, you can do that manually with `touch`), but there's no way to hide the [ctime (inode change time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)#ctime). The ctime is the last time the file was modified in some way.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't know that ctime was not easily changeable with touch either, related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36021/how-can-i-change-change-date-of-file